# Mass change column default values in database project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, default, database-project

I have a Visual Studio 2013 database project, in which I would like to change all GUID columns with a default of `newid()` to `newsequentialid()`.

Using the following query to identify the columns:

```
SELECT so.name AS table_name, 
    sc.name AS column_name, 
    sm.text AS default_value
FROM sys.sysobjects so
JOIN sys.syscolumns sc ON sc.id = so.id
LEFT JOIN sys.syscomments SM ON sm.id = sc.cdefault
WHERE so.xtype = 'U'
    AND sm.text = '(newid())'
ORDER BY so.[name], sc.colid
```

there are a total of 62 columns in 62 tables.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio other than going to each table definition one-by-one and changing the default value?

Comment: if that query gives you the table names, then you dynamically build `alter` statements to change the tables in a loop. e.g. `'alter table ' + result.tablename + ' change ....'`

Comment: That will change the actual database sitting on the DB server, not the .sql files that make up the database project.

Comment: Find and replace in all *.sql files in the project would work to do that in the project. Not sure how it would handle changes to your servers, though. I'd try the find/replace first and then maybe see if you need to tweak the refactorlog in some fashion to handle refactoring.

Comment: Find and replace in files is exactly what I was looking for. Changes to the server are done via schema compare or publish script, so scripting the dropping/recreation of the named constraints is taken care of by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and replace in all *.sql files in the project would work to do that in the project. I'd try the find/replace first and then maybe see if you need to tweak the refactorlog in some fashion to handle refactoring.